# jquery hide a div thats loaded by jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm creating a website and use jquery to post a form.
When I press the submit button a jquery function posts the form to a php file.
The php file creates a result error or success. The result is echoed by the php file
and jquery file outputs the echo using the `.html()` method.

I call the html output `#result.`

So my question is how do I hide the `#result` using **jquery**. This has to happen after 5 seconds.

This works fine when `#result` is loaded with the page. But not when `#result` is loaded like is said above.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
      $('#result').slideUp(500);  
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your JavaScript code, including the part that makes the post request?

Comment: Can't you do `setTimeout` in the `success` callback of your AJAX function?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to always have the empty result div in your html and just keep it hidden. This way whenever you get a result from the AJAX you can just change the html, show it, then slide it up again.

```
$("#result").html(AJAX RESULT);
$("#result").show();
setTimeout(function(){ 
      $('#result').slideUp(500);  
}, 5000);
```

This will change the html of the div then show it. Then hide it after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $.ajax with the *success* callback option or use .done() method. Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://someurl/",
    success: function(data){ $('#result').html('success').show(); },
    error: function(data){ $('#result').html('error').show(); }
}).done(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
       $('#result').slideUp(500);  
   }, 5000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thing is *#result* is sometimes dynamically added to DOM, and jQuery functions are usually loaded when document is ready, to solve this issue you must listen to DOM changes. If for some reason you're not using AJAX or need another approach, you could try this:

```
function hideMsg(){
    // Hide dynamically added div
    setTimeout(function(){ 
          $('#result').slideUp(500);  
    }, 5000);
}
// Listen DOM changes
$('.document').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", hideMsg);
```

In order for this to work, you must change **.document** by your document wrapper (where your message will be displayed).

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/laelitenetwork/GUxgX/

Cheers.

Comment: this worked prety good, but it crashes my browser after a while. the solution is to send the javascript code that hides the message with the message.

Comment: The downside of this approach is that if message wrapper changes frequently, it will run this function every time. So, in order to avoid that, you should add an empty DIV exclusively to display messages.

However, I agree it'd be better to do this when AJAX request is done, check @dododo example.